# Question about statement in Oster (2019): variation in a control

Tags: regression, econometrics, goodness-of-fit, controlling-for-a-variable, omitted-variable-bias

In [Oster (2019)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2016.1227711?journalCode=ubes20), she discusses how authors typically include controls and examine coefficient stability as a way to test for presence of confounding, and points out that researchers should consider how $R^2$ moves with the addition of controls as well. I have a simple question about one claim early in the paper:

> Even under this most optimistic assumption, however, coefficient
> movements alone are not a sufficient statistic to calculate bias. To
> illustrate why, consider the case of a researcher estimating wage
> returns to education with individual ability as the only counfounder,
> and where there are two orthogonal components of ability, one of which
> has a higher variance than the other. Assume wages would be fully
> explained if both ability components were observed but, in practice,
> the researcher sees only one of the two. **The coefficient will appear
> much more stable if the observed ability control is the lower variance
> one, but this is not because the bias is smaller but simply because
> less of the wage outcome is explained by the controls.**

Can someone explain why this bolded sentence makes sense? I know if a control has less variance, it's coefficient has higher standard errors, but I dont understand intuitively (or mathematically) why this implies that the $R^2$ would move by less, and therefore the main coefficient of interest would seem more 'stable' to the inclusion of the control. Why does the $R^2$ move by less if the control is lower variance compared to one that has higher variance?